# HttpRequestException when processing document in Azure Form Recognizer

Tags: azure, docker, azure-cognitive-services

We are experiencing difficulties with the Invoice Azure Form Recognizer container. After we send a document for processing, we receive a "failed" status. We tried sending in both ways: application/json and application/octet-stream, and the error always appears.

To be specific, here's an example of the response:

```
{
  "status": "failed",
  "createdDateTime": "2024-01-02T15:53:56Z",
  "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2024-01-02T15:53:56Z",
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "An unexpected error occurred.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "HttpRequestException",
        "message": "Could not connect to upstream host: An invalid request URI was provided. Either the request URI must be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.",
        "target": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The way we launch this container:

```
~$ dockerun --rm -it -p 5000:5050 --memory 16g --cpus 6 -e Eula=accept -e Billing=https://xxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com -e ApiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/form-recognizer/invoice-3.0
```

The console shows the error:

```
fail: formrecognizerinvoice[0]

      {"ClassName":"Microsoft.CloudAI.Containers.VDI.Common.Errors.VdiException","Message":"HttpRequestException","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at Microsoft.CloudAI.Containers.VDI.OnPremises.Common.Handler.FrBaseHandler.HttpPostAsync(String requestUri, HttpContent content)\n   at Microsoft.CloudAI.Containers.VDI.OnPremises.Common.Handler.Fr30GaUpstreamHandler.PostUpstreamInternalRequest(String modelId, Byte[] stream, ServiceMessage message)\n   at Microsoft.CloudAI.Containers.VDI.OnPremises.Common.Handler.Fr30GaUpstreamHandler.HandleMessageAsync(ServiceMessage message)","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":null,"HResult":-2146233088,"Source":"Microsoft.CloudAI.Containers.VDI.OnPremises.Common","WatsonBuckets":null} SubscriptionId='' RequestId='ebab790b-3e6e-4c0b-af93-9396cb609fd8' Timestamp='' buildVersion='1.2.367.0-20230707.6-27dcd7ae972075713bb9e4477fe50c6e623f1596' hostId='a71ffbc4bc9f' serviceName='formrecognizerinvoice' namespace='vdi' Namesapce='vdi' fileSizeInBytes='100040' processedPageIndex='0' toSecondaryQueue='False' totalPageCount='2' fileType='Pdf' apiName='invoice-2022-08-31' ocrModelName='2023-07-31' scenario='fr_async_layout' resultNameEnum='UpstreamFRResult' ocrResolution='Standard' errorCode='HttpRequestException'
```

How can we resolve this issue?

We are testing the same file with another container: Layout Form Recognizer, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/containers/install-run?view=doc-intel-3.0.0&preserve-view=true&tabs=invoice#required-supporting-containers), `Invoice` feature container required a supporting `Layout` container.

So, the issue can be due to you are launching the container without supporting layout container and can be fixed by including supporting container in your request.

Below is a sample YAML `invoice` configure for reference:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  azure-cognitive-service-invoice:
    container_name: azure-cognitive-service-invoice
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/form-recognizer/invoice-3.0
    environment:
        - EULA=accept
        - billing={FORM_RECOGNIZER_ENDPOINT_URI}
        - apiKey={FORM_RECOGNIZER_KEY}
        - AzureCognitiveServiceLayoutHost=http://azure-cognitive-service-layout:5000
    ports:
      - "5000:5050"
  azure-cognitive-service-layout:
    container_name: azure-cognitive-service-layout
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/form-recognizer/layout-3.0
    environment:
        - EULA=accept
        - billing={FORM_RECOGNIZER_ENDPOINT_URI}
        - apiKey={FORM_RECOGNIZER_KEY}
```